# Script to load JqueryMobile files after a specific media query

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

i am begining to play around with JqueryMobile but some JqueryMobile scripts conflict with other stuff like non jqueryM menus, so i would like to exectue those JqueryMobile scripts only from 768px and below or these media query:
 and

Any ideas how to do that, have being looking around how to do it and not succesful with them so i was hoping you guys could give me fresher ideas. My site is thjis: http://pugle.net/test2/index.php
The problem is that JqueryM script does not allow to click on the links on the main menu and this main menu shows before 768px..so thats why i would like JqueryM script to load below any 768px screen.

so THANX GUYS!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [awesome media queries in JavaScript](http://wicky.nillia.ms/enquire.js) can help you out. It's quite easy to implement - here's an example of what a likely solution might like look:

```
enquire.register('only screen and (max-width: 768px)', {
  match: function() {
    $.getScript('jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js', function() {
      ...
    });
  },
  unmatch: function() {
    ...
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanx Wynand, kind of beginner on JS, what would you put on those .... or in $.getScript('jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js', function() { ... (WHAT WOULD U PUT HERE) }); - WHAT SOME console.log() like in the example website u gave me thanx.

Comment: With `$.getScript`, the second argument is an optional _success_ callback and fired once the script has been loaded. You can then safely execute jQuery Mobile-specific code or any other code that has a dependency on it. With `enquire.register`, _unmatch_ is also an optional callback and fired when the media query changes from a matched to an unmatched state. Depending on what you're aiming to accomplish, you might want to add a certain class name to a container element in the _match_ or `$.getScript` _success_ callback, remove it in the _unmatch_ callback and have it mapped to specific JS/CSS.

Comment: Thanx Wnyand but this solution does not work for me as u suggested, anymore  JS media queries, like these for dummies though (as u can see my level hehe)

Comment: I noticed from another question that you also looked at jRespond, although at first blush it would seem that jRespond is pixel-based whereas enquire.js actually responds (pun intended) to real media queries. Either should allow you to load a specific script only for a specific screen width and under. When you say it's not working, do you mean it's not loading the script or is it loading the script but you're experiencing a different issue?

Comment: oh thanx for ur help again, i mean the script does not load. Here is the code in case u can help me, well its basically the same as urs above, enquire.register('only screen and (max-width: 768px)', {
  match: function() {
    $.getScript('jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js', function() {
 });}});  Anyways u can see all i am doing here http://pugle.net/test2/index.php actually between the quotes <!--  JqueryM starts here-->  Anyways i would like also to include the jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css script also beside the .js let me know if u can make these work, thanx again for ur persistent help!

Comment: and about the JSrespond yes i am getting pretty desparate on finding an script to make these work, it obviously looks like my amateur level is the problem not the actual scripts!